# How do pilots protect their necks in jet fighters?

Tags: safety, military, pilots

My uncle once told a story of a pilot forgetting to strap his neck, which snapped mid-flight and the plane crashed. How do pilots strap their neck properly?

Comment: Your neck won't "snap off", most flight suits don't have neck support so I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am just saying things my "Brother of my mother" told me thats it

Comment: This may not have an application to reality, that's what I'm saying... I've never heard of internal decapitation in fighter pilots, flight suit or not.

Comment: Consider the possibility that "brother of your mother" (uncle, in English) either 1) doesn't know what he's talking about; or 2) is telling you "tall tales" for some reason.

Comment: @RonBeyer so why would an fighter jet (tag) pilot would die mid-flight other than heart attack etc ?

Comment: Blacking out would do it, and has done it. Modern flight suits are fitted to the pilot, as long as they are on, they are "tightened up". The air pressure system does the rest.

Comment: They don't need to, because the neck is great at handling vertically upward G force which is the only direction of high G on a fighter. It's not like race cars you have a lot of lateral and front/back Gs that can indeed break the neck.

Comment: I think the way they protect their neck is by shooting down the other guy first - just a thought.

Answer (score 6):

[image]
([HANS device](http://www.grandprix.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/a_z_page_medium_only/public/image/H_-_HANS_result.jpg); [pilot helmet](http://www.salimbeti.com/aviation/images/helmets/scorpion-03.jpg))

There is no sudden deceleration experienced in a fighter jet that would warrant the device shown above on the left used by auto racers (not even a carrier launch/arrest is compared to crashing a racing car).

It would help in a crash, but fighter pilots have an easier option, which is to eject. Also notice the back of the helmet on the right, it's shaped so the pilot can look around freely, unlike the one on the left.

Comment: I think your last sentence deserves a bit of attention: restricting movement of the neck (which is essentially what a neck support does) would also restrict visibility, which is likely to be much more deadly to a fighter pilot than the extremely remote chance of getting into a lateral high-G maneuver.